# Joomla security - fingerprinting attacks with htaccess

Tags: security, .htaccess-configuration

I've been playing with my htaccess file to better secure Joomla but I'm stuck at this example ([reference](http://docs.joomla.org/Htaccess_examples_%28security%29)):

```
## Referrer filtering for common media files. Replace with your own domain name.
## This blocks most common fingerprinting attacks ;)
## Note: Change www\.example\.com with your own domain name, substituting the
## dots with \.  i.e. use www\.example\.com for www.example.com
RewriteRule ^images/stories/([^/]+/)*([^/.]+\.)+(jp(e?g|2)?|png|gif|bmp|css|js|swf|ico)$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} .
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^https?://(www\.)?example\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule \.(jp(e?g|2)?|png|gif|bmp|css|js|swf|ico)$ - [F]
```

I've added this example as a test and it messes up my site (obviously changing example.com to my site). I guess I'm not really sure what this is actually doing. `images/stories/` doesn't exist on my server so what is this trying do?

I'm using Joomla 2.5

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*First of all, I'm by no means an expert in `.htaccess` usage.*

The code you've posted will not allow anyone to hotlink your content, the only exception being defined in the following line:

```
RewriteRule ^images/stories/([^/]+/)*([^/.]+\.)+(jp(e?g|2)?|png|gif|bmp|css|js|swf|ico)$ - [L]
```

The line `RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^https?://(www\.)?example\.com [NC]` defines the domain that is allowed to access any content, thus event a tiny error will stop Joomla from loading CSS, JS, images etc. from other directories. You should double-check this.

You can also replace line #5 with this:

```
RewriteRule ^((components|modules|templates|images|plugins|media)/.*\.(jpe|jpg|jpeg|jp2|jpe2|png|gif|bmp|css|js|swf|html|mpg|mp3|mpeg|mp4|avi|wav|ogg|ogv|xls|xlsx|doc|docx|ppt|pptx|zip|rar|pdf|xps|txt|7z|svg|odt|ods|odp|flv|mov|ico|htm))$ $1 [L]
```

I found some additional info [here](https://www.akeebabackup.com/support/admin-tools/9792-htaccess-blocks-access-for-firefox.html):

> The idea is that if you're going to disable HTTP referer validation,
>   be consistent and do it site-wide to avoid hard-to-trace problems.
>   Besides, this feature only offers limited protection against
>   fingerprinting attacks (i.e. attempts of hackers to fly under the
>   radar in order to figure out which Joomla! release you're using).

Basically, the code snippet you're using might cause more problems than it's worth.

Comment: Thanks for finding that reference. I still don't know the issue with it but I think for now there is no point in adding it.